# Need to query MySQL data without knowing exact schema name

Tags: mysql, query, syntax

I have an issue where the MySQL schema contains more than one active schema and when I go to query a set of tables, I get the error that I need to select the schema.

I know I can just find the name and use the database, but I'm having to search our farm which consists of some 50k individual database names.

Is there a way I can query INFORMATION_SCHEMA for the table_schema which ends in _1 or _2 or any _# - `(REGEXP '[a-z]_[[:digit:]]')` and then pass that schema name to a select?

Say the schema is database_1

`SELECT table.column FROM database_1.table WHERE table.column = 'foobar' ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1;`

I just need to figure out how to pass the database name without using the actual database.

I hope my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: *when I go to query a set of tables, I get the **error that I need to select the schema.*** - this means that your current client session have no current/default database. Test - try to execute `USE needed_database_name;` as the most first SQL statement in your session.

Comment: *Is there a way I can query INFORMATION_SCHEMA for the table_schema ... and then pass that schema name to a select?* You may query for the database names list which matches your criteria then execute `USE` statement and set one of these DBnames as current one. `USE` statement must be executed usng dynamic SQL in this case, because database name cannot be parametrized in this statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can search the information_schema for the one you want, but you can't do that and also use it as a schema identifier in the same query where you look it up.

You will have to do it in two queries:

1. Look up the schema name.
2. Format a second query using the result of that lookup.